# vuex sub modules - pros vs cons

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

My company have a really big application, with a lot (!) of data.

We have an argument using 3 modules for the main areas, and the main as flat module in store,

or using sub-modules as much as needed. (for each main sub-module about 6-8 sub-modules)

I wanted to get opinion only from people with experience in complex application using vuex. 
Is it better to keep the module flat? or to use sub-modules?

Pros vs Cons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go by [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), It really makes sense to have submodules for different part of your system. It makes the feature enhancement easy and adding in one submodule does not alter anything in other modules, which makes collaboration also easy with different people working on different modules of your application.

Vuex submodules also helps keeping states of different submodules isolated from each other, otherwise it is too easy to have all the state variables mingled among each other. it implicitly emphases this discipline.

But in case your application is very simplistic and it is too much trouble to separate those in different submodules, than it will be definitely a overkill to use submodules.

Comment: lets say we have 3 main areas in the application. 3 modules will be enough? We need to learn from experience....

Comment: If the 3 are fairly independent from each other and each one is big enough to be a module in itself, you can go ahead with it.